# Argument of type '"shop"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"items" | "cart"'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ngrx

I did some searching around but didnt seem to find an answer. I'm new to Angular, for this project im working on an webstore, i did use a tutorial but came across an error.

```
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { GetItems } from '../store/actions';
import { Product } from '../product/product.component';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
  })
  export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private store: Store<{ items: Product[]; cart: [] }>) {
      store.pipe(select('shop')).subscribe(data => (this.items = data.items));
    }

    items: Product[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
      this.store.dispatch(new GetItems());
    }
  }
```

the error im getting is:

> src/app/home/home.component.ts:13:25 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
>     Overload 1 of 8, '(mapFn: (state: { items: Product[]; cart: []; }, props: unknown) => unknown, props?: unknown): (source$: Observable<{ items: Product[]; cart: []; }>) => Observable', gave the following error.
>       Argument of type '"shop"' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: { items: Product[]; cart: []; }, props: unknown) => unknown'.
>     Overload 2 of 8, '(key: "items" | "cart"): (source$: Observable<{ items: Product[]; cart: []; }>) => Observable<[] | Product[]>', gave the following error.
>       Argument of type '"shop"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"items" | "cart"'.
>
> 13       store.pipe(select('shop')).subscribe(data => (this.items = data.items));
>                              ~~~~~~
>
> src/app/home/home.component.ts:13:71 - error TS2339: Property 'items' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
>
> 13       store.pipe(select('shop')).subscribe(data => (this.items = data.items));

I can't seem to find the problem. Even starting the app is giving me difficulties. Sometimes it starts in one go, sometimes i need to try it 5 times. But the weird thing is, the moment it starts, everything works as inteded, but with errors in my CMD.

I feel like there's something wrong with my ngrx/store.

Comment: I tink using an object literal in a generic is wrong. You need a type not an object. Try:
type SHOP_OBJECT_TYPE = {  items: Product[]; cart: [];  }

and in your constructor:
private store: Store<SHOP_OBJECT_TYPE>

Comment: unfortunate this didnt work, but i might have screwed up the first part, does it need to replace anything, or should it just be added? the constructor part is clear for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following things to get more specific error - 
1) Create an interface (AppState) and pass it while you initiating the Store, which would be the initial state -

```
private store: Store<AppState>
```

2) Create an Selector/FeatureSelector to select any part of the state.

You can find the more detail here - https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors